# Remote storybook build not working on Netlify

Tags: build, netlify, storybook

I am trying to set up Netlify build for storybook. npm run build storybook is working fine on my local, however it's not working in Netlify; this is the error I'm getting.

```
failed during stage 'building site': Deploy directory 'storybook-static' does not exist
```

Here is my local storybook build and Netlify build settings.

[local npm run build storybook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2URF.png)

[Netlify build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiOEz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your publish directory on Netlify should be set to `build` rather than `storybook-static`

Answer (score 0):

You've probably resolved this by now, but just in case -

The command you are running is `npm run build storybook` when it should be `npm run build-storybook`

Comment: Looks like more suitable for a comment

Comment: @AntonTokmakov How is this not an answer?